# PHP script to monitor process and write status to a file

Tags: shell-script, php

I want to write a php script for monitoring particular process using top command and write into the file.

I use `top -p pid` for monitoring a particular process and also i write a shell script for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/home/test/nik/myscriptoutput2";
TIMEOUT=5;
PROCNAME='init';
counter=0;

echo 'counter value is :- '$counter
while [ $counter -lt 3 ]
do
        echo 'inside while'
        top -b -n 1 |grep $PROCNAME >> $FILE
        sleep $TIMEOUT
        counter=$((counter+1))
        echo $counter
done
echo 'while loop end'
```

This script will monitor init process after 5 sec for 3 times and write the it into file.

How can I write the same script in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
top -bd 5 -n 3 -p `pidof init` >> /home/test/nik/myscriptoutput2
```

instead of your whole script...

In PHP you can use

```
<?php
   $file  = "/home/test/nik/myscriptoutput2";
   $output = shell_exec('top -bd 5 -n 3 -p `pidof init`');
   file_put_contents($file, $output);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you it working successfully but using top -b -n 1 |grep init command.

Comment: top -bd 5 -n 3 -p `pidof init` this command is not working it will show error (top: bad pid 'pidof init')

Comment: You need to use backticks (`) instead of single quotes (').